# check image exist on url in windows store app

Tags: windows, image

I have a windows store application, where I want to check if an image exists on specified URL. If yes, then image will be display, otherwise not.
I've  tried File.Exists(), but in that case it gives me error.

The type or namespace name 'File' does not exist in the namespace 'System.IO' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Though, I have already added System.IO, but still it gives error.

Can anybody please suggest me how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no System.IO.File namespace in windows .Net for Store Apps. There is something like Windows.Storage.FileIO but no File namespace.

**edit:**

try something like this:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("YourURL");

request.Method = "HEAD";

bool pictureExisting;
try {
    request.GetResponse();
    pictureExisting= true;
} catch {
   pictureExisting= false;
}
```

Comment: So how can i check if an image exists on specified URL or not? Can you give me some example ?

Comment: I tried your code,it always gives pictureExisting=true whether image length 0 or greater 

I have changed one line request.GetResponse(); to  request.GetResponseAsync(); ..that's why i am always getting true?

Comment: Yes, you're right. When using GetResponseAsync() you'll always get a pictureExisting = true. My code snipped just works fine.

Comment: but when i use GetResponse() it gives me error.

I have already added System.Net.Http

'System.Net.HttpWebRequest' does not contain a definition for 'GetResponse' and no extension method 'GetResponse' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Net.HttpWebRequest' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)